# jquery zebra_accordion expands the div linked to from other page

Tags: jquery, accordion

I am trying to have my jquery zebra_accordion expand(show) a specified div based on a URL variable passed from a link on another page. From looking at other posts and forums, I've tried customizing it's functions.js file from this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        new $.Zebra_Accordion('#Zebra_Accordion1'); });
```

To something like this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var torun = self.location.search.slice(1);
    if (torun==expand-yourself) {
        new $.Zebra_Accordion($('.Zebra_Accordion1'), {
    'show': 0
});
        } 
    if (torun==half-day-evening) {
        new $.Zebra_Accordion($('.Zebra_Accordion1'), {
    'show': 1
});
        }       
    if (torun==private-lessons) {
        new $.Zebra_Accordion($('.Zebra_Accordion1'), {
    'show': 2
});
        }       
    else {
        new $.Zebra_Accordion('#Zebra_Accordion1');
    } });
```

The "expand-yourself", "half-day-evening", and "private-lesson" are the variables being passed and the numbers that follow 'show' are the numbers of the divs in the accordion. I got that little snippet from the Zebra_Accordion's configuration instructions, [here](http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/zebra-accordion).

My javascript skills are just about zero and it doesn't work at all. Am I even putting this function in the right place?

Here is a link to the website I'm building: 
[www.thehumanualway.com](http://thehumanualway.com)
The links are on home page under where it says "Classes" and the accordion is on the Classes page.

I posted a question on the zebra_accordian website, but it looks like it's not moderated anymore. Help me stackoverflow, you're my only hope.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The links from the other page pass a parameter called "tab" in the URL using this:

```
<a href="javascript:location='/classes/?tab=expand-yourself';">Expand Yourself</a>
```

And here is the correct function. Hope someone else finds this helpful!

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

            if (window.location.search.indexOf('tab=expand-yourself') > -1) {
                    var myAccordion = new $.Zebra_Accordion($('#Zebra_Accordion1'));
myAccordion.show(0);
            } 

            else if (window.location.search.indexOf('tab=half-day-evening') > -1) {
                    var myAccordion = new $.Zebra_Accordion($('#Zebra_Accordion1'));
myAccordion.show(1);
            }

            else {
                    new $.Zebra_Accordion('#Zebra_Accordion1');
            }
});
```